# blazor wasm using new Claim("roles", role) cause @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] not work

Tags: jwt, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

when I use new claims.Add(new Claim(**ClaimTypes.Role**, role)); **@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]** and **AuthorizeView Roles="admin"** works correctly. But when I use claims.Add(new Claim(**"Roles"**, role)); **AuthorizeView(Roles="admin")** doesn't work and show an error in browser console:

"RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (admin)"

I tested **options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "Roles";** in **AddIdentity()** and **RoleClaimType = "Roles"** in **TokenValidationParameters** but those don't work.

How can we use our "Roles" key instead of ClaimTypes.Role?

My project is here : http://github.com/mammadkoma/Attendance

Answer (score 0):

AuthenticationStateProvider :

```
return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromToken(token), "jwtAuthType", ClaimTypes.Name, "Roles")));

var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromToken(token), "jwtAuthType", ClaimTypes.Name, "Roles"));
```

https://github.com/mammadkoma/Attendance/blob/master/Attendance/Client/Configs/AuthStateProvider.cs

Answer (score 0):

We have to use **RoleClaimType = "Roles"** in **TokenValidationParameters** :

```
public static class TokenConfig
{
    public static void AddJwt(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.JwtSecretKey)),
                RoleClaimType = "Roles",
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                //OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                //{
                //    var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TokenValidatorService>();
                //    return new Task(new Action(() => { }));
                //},
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TokenValidatorService>();
                    return tokenValidatorService.ValidateAsync(context);
                },
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            };
        });
    }
}
```